# (OPEN_GL & LWJGL) glDrawElements() does not draw vertices

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Good day,

I have seen this question multiple times around but the answers don't seems to apply to my case.
I have a JAVA class that should draw a sphere using VBOs. 
In the constructor I define the vertex and the index buffer and calculate the coordinates for each vertex:

```
public sphereHelper(float fRadius, int iSlices, int iStacks)

    {  
        FBVertices = GLDrawHelper.directFloatBuffer(new float[iSlices*iStacks*4*3]); 
        FBVertices.clear();

        IBVerticesIndex = GLDrawHelper.directIntBuffer(new int[iSlices*iStacks*4]);
        IBVerticesIndex.clear();
        int index=0;
```

//after this we have long code that calculates each vertex' position x,y,z and puts it into the vertex buffer,    also putting together the indexbuffer IBVerticesIndex to point at then, followed by:

```
VertexBufferID= GL15.glGenBuffers();
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,VertexBufferID);
GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,FBVertices,GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);

//generate unique buffer id(like texture id) to bind  to the GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER
VertexIndexBufferID=GL15.glGenBuffers();
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexIndexBufferID);
GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBVerticesIndex, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);}
```

My draw() function looks like this:

```
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VertexBufferID);
GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);  
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,VertexIndexBufferID);        
GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES,IBVerticesIndex.limit(),GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
```

It tried a lot of things but glDrawElements() just doesn't draw anything.
This is extra confusing, as `glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0,FBVertices.capacity());` does draw as it should.

I'm thankful for any suggestions!

EDIT: In [here](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/The_Quad_with_DrawElements) they use different OPENGL versions together, so i thought this might work. Down in the comments someone suggested this might be a problem?

Comment: If this is really about OpenGL 1.1, then you are not allowed to use any functions from the GL15 (OpenGL 1.5) or GL20 (OpenGL 2.0) packages.

Comment: That suprised me too. In the tutorial over her http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/The_Quad_with_DrawElements, they throw those together and it works. My problem with using ony OPEN GL 1.1 is, that i don't get how to set up the index buffer. 
To my understanding you would define the vertex buffer using   GL11.glVertexPointer(3,0,FBVertices);
but how ould you proceed with the indices. There is no glBindBuffer() in 1.1, so i can't manually apply them to GL_ELEMENTS_ARRAY_BUFFER.
So how would i draw the whole thing using the indices?

Comment: In OpenGL 1.1 there is no such thing as a vertex buffer or index buffer. Drawing happened there by calling `glVertex...`. But one should definitely not use that anymore. I don't see any reason nowadays to just use OpenGL 1.1, so you might want to remove that restriction from the title.

Comment: @BDL:  OpenGL 1.1 introduced vertex arrays, one didn't have to use immediate mode anymore. But those client-side arrays shouldn't be used nowadays either...

Comment: Yeah, but this is part of an assignment where we have to use LWJGL with OPENGL 1.1.  So there is no way of using an index buffer in 1.1?


We are told to use the index buffer directly within glDrawElements(PrimitiveType,indexBuffer);
with indexBuffer being an IntBuffer. This doesn't work for me. Is this 1.1 anymore? 

@derhass: the vertex arrays you talk about are just "vertex buffers" then?
That you feed into glVertexPointer()?

Comment: those are just client side memory buffer you can stuff into an of the attrib pointer functions, as well as `glDrawElements`. I don't know how java deals with them.

Comment: @derhass alright. So they are vertex buffers probably, but also with doublicates as there is no index buffer . Thanks so far, i will take the 1.1 out of my question. Maybe someone has an idea how to get it to work with one of the newer versions.

Comment: @Don_M: There _are_ element index arrays in GL1.1, as I already mentioned in my previous comment. There are generally no buffer objects in GL 1.1. You seem to confuse both of these concepts somehow.

Comment: @derhass Aaah. Our professor told us to use Buffer objects instead of arrays for Vertices and Indices out of performance reasons (in Java, they are the only possibility to allocated data directly to my understanding). So if i use normal int/float arrays for indices and vertices it should work like this (?): 

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices[]);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices[]);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

using OpenGL 1.1?

Comment: @Don_M: conceptually, yes. I just don't know have java will handle this, that is, if you can pass in native java arrays, or if you have to use some jav bytebuffer abstraction or whatever...

Comment: @derhass Alright, thanks. I will play around with it.